# Conditional Concatenate and Autofill with Value from Adjacent Column

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

```
Sub Concatenate ()  
    Dim LastRow As Long  
    Dim i As Long  
        LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  
            ActiveSheet.Range("K2").Formula = "= TODAY() - I2"
            Range("K2").Select  
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K2:K" & LastRow)  
        For i = 2 To LastRow  
            If Range("K" & i).Value < 5 Then Range("J2:J" & i).Value = "Week of" & "" & ("I2:I" & i)  
        Next i  
End Sub
```

I have a spreadsheet that lists item numbers in Column A, and corresponding dates in column I. Not every item will have a date, so I'm basing the LastRow on Column A to work around the gaps. I want dates in the past to return 0 in column J. I want future dates to return "Week of __" there the __ is the date in column I.

I'm not the most familiar with VBA, and I've run into a bit of a snag. With the above, everything returns "Week of9". I know it's a simple answer, but I have been Googling for an hour. I just need to know the syntax to make the above return the value of "I" at the end of the concatenate as it loops down the rows. If this is a duplicate question, I apologize.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your condition should be:

```
If Range("K" & i).Value < 5 Then Range("J" & i).Value = "Week of " & Range("I" & i)
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the input. It definitely simplifies it. Looking back, I'm not sure why I did it that way anyway. I think it was a case of staring too long. I tries it this way, but it returns the actual row number "Week of I9", "Week of I10", ect instead of the actual date in the cell.